# Setting the value of a spreadsheet cell using a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a script that runs on a timed trigger once a day, and its purpose is to copy a template spreadsheet and rename it using the current date.  In addition, I would like to set the value of a specific cell within the newly created spreadsheet to the current date.

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'EST', 'MMddyy');
var newLiveFeedName = "Live Feed ("+date+")"; 
var newLiveFeed = currentLiveFeedTemplate.makeCopy(newLiveFeedName);
newLiveFeed.SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange('G2').setValue(date);
```

I am getting an error that indicates that the getSheetByName() function is undefined.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newLiveFeed` is a spreadsheet object, so try simply like that :

(assuming that  `currentLiveFeedTemplate` is the `ActiveSpreadsheet()`)

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'EST', 'MMddyy');
var newLiveFeedName = "Live Feed ("+date+")"; 
var newLiveFeed = currentLiveFeedTemplate.copy(newLiveFeedName);
newLiveFeed.getSheetByName("Summary").getRange('G2').setValue(date);
```

Comment: This script is meant to be triggered independent of any spreadsheet and thus will not have an active spreadsheet open.  Can editing a cell be accomplished in this way or do I need to have the script open up the spreadsheet before it edits the cell.

Comment: if the script is executed independently of the spreadsheet you will have to define the source spreadsheet using `var currentLiveFeedTemplate=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`, id being the ID of the source spreadsheet.

Comment: indeed: `SpreadsheetApp.openById(newLiveFeed.getId()).getSheetByName("Summary").getRange('G2').setValue(date);`

Comment: Jonathan, your line worked exactly as I was intending for my script.  And Serge, thank you for leading me up to that point.  Being somewhat new to Google App Scripts, I didn't recognize that I had to have the script virtually "open" the spreadsheet in order to edit cells.  The rest of my script that has been successful up until now has merely copied and moved the spreadsheet file around.